# LinkButton onclick not working after postback

Tags: 2013, javascript

This linkbutton stops working after I do a postback. The JS will still run and will correctly return true/false.  The postback that breaks this is exporting a data table to Excel. Note: this code works as expected outside of SharePoint.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnGenerateReport" runat="server" 
    CssClass="generateReport button wide"
    OnClick="btnGenerateReport_Click" 
    OnClientClick="if (!ValidateMe()) return false;" 
    UseSubmitBehavior="true" CausesValidation="false">
    Generate Report
</asp:LinkButton> 


System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(memoryStream);
            CsvHelper.CsvWriter writer = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(streamWriter);
            foreach (DataColumn column in tableToExport.Columns)
            {
                writer.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
            }
            writer.NextRecord();

            foreach (DataRow row in tableToExport.Rows)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < tableToExport.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    writer.WriteField(row[i]);
                }
                writer.NextRecord();
            }

            streamWriter.Flush();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Expires = 0;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ".csv");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: Post the excel generation code. I think the issue lies with the way you are handling Response object.

Comment: Sorry, I read this as *potluck.  They held an office get-together and stuff broke.

Comment: found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336883/post-back-does-not-work-after-writing-files-to-response-in-asp-net

Comment: The answer is saying it is SharePoint related.

Comment: Can confirm that. The spFormOnSubmitCalled indeed blocks multiple postbacks on the same page. [See my answer here for some workarounds too if you still need it](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/21334/5173) - I could also copy the relevant content here too if you like. Anyway, voting to reopen this. As a suggestion, you could add some pointer in the question to indicate that the issue is SharePoint relate, for example you could add a notice that say that the code works as expected outside of SharePoint.

Comment: I'm reopening it so you can post the answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because of Sharepoint sets the `_spFormOnSubmitCalled` to `true` and disallow more submits unless it is set back to false as occured in postback behavior.

So at `OnClientClick` event you should set `_spFormOnSubmitCalled` to `false;`

**The final code should look like**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnGenerateReport" runat="server" 
    CssClass="generateReport button wide"
    OnClick="btnGenerateReport_Click" 
    OnClientClick="javascript:setFormSubmitToFalse()" 
    UseSubmitBehavior="true" CausesValidation="false">
    Generate Report
</asp:LinkButton> 

function setFormSubmitToFalse() {
    setTimeout(function () { _spFormOnSubmitCalled = false; }, 3000);
    return true;
}
```